# How to connect four monitors to a 15-inch MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

Considering the latest 15-inch MacBook Pro that has four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports, I'm wondering if it's possible to connect four 1080p monitors to it.

I'm assuming I could connect three monitors to the three Thunderbolt ports , since one is reserved for power, but how would i connect the forth?

I'm not planing to game or do video editing of this machine, but otherwise, how will the performance be with four monitors (assuming this is possible)

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the 15” MacBook Pro supports “Up to four displays with 3840x2160 resolution at 60Hz at over a billion colours” in addition to the built-in display. You don’t have to reserve a port for power, you can run off battery, or find a display that will deliver power to the MacBook Pro. Or you can daisy-chain the displays, and run one of them by connecting it to another display and not directly to the MacBook Pro.

Comment: `daisy-chain the displays` .. not sure if my monitors support this. I see there are Thunderbolt 3 to Dual HDMI adapters out there.. could I use that? Also, do u have the source?

Comment: i think i found the source https://www.galmac.ie/macbook/macbook-pro/13-inch-2ghz-macbook-pro-space-grey-1309-1310-1311-1312-1313-1314-1315-1316-1317-1318.htm.html